# Getting output from external SAT solver

Tags: alloy

The Alloy Analyzer offers a "Output CNF to File" option, which means that I can send the constraints generated by Alloy to my favourite SAT solver. But how can I transfer the SAT result back to Alloy, so that I can visualise the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't. I agree it would be useful to have that option.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame. Thanks anyway. Here's hoping for the new feature in future releases! :)